# Чем отличается установка официального React от этого туториала?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

Я устанавливал React в папку с помощью официального туториала

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Но почему то я вспомнил про все эти webpack и babel, и тут попалась статья как начать проект с помочью этих двух элементов и еще разных по типу scss и так далее. Вот ссылка на статью: https://dev.to/iamismile/how-to-setup-webpack-and-babel-for-react-59ph и я боюсь сейчас трогать папку, потому что там всегда что то да ломается, я еще новичек в вебе и постоянно что то делаю не то.

Вопрос:

Если кратко то я сделал вот эти шаги:

mkdir react-setup-tutorial
cd react-setup-tutorial
mkdir public src
touch public/index.html src/app.js

далее создал html и положил туда кусок кода из туториалла.

продолжил:

```
npm init -y

npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

создал и положил опять кусок кода webpack.config.json

добавил код в package.json

ВАЖНЫЙ ЭТАП: Что это? `npm install react react-dom`

Смущает что загрузка прошла быстро в отличии от официального туториалла.
Наводит на то что все эти этапы делаются в официальном на автомате

Далее сделал следующие шаги, опишу кратко:

```
(1) => Install & Configure Babel 
(2) => Configure Source Map
(3) => Install DevServer
(4) => Loading the Styles
```

Comment: Сделать и сравнить оба в чем проблемы. Про100 официальный сделает кучу работы за вас под капотом а в вашем туториале ручками. И официальный старается подготовить максимально общий проект для начала. Это ведь не говорит что его менять нельзя. Просто точка входа в одном случае котлован под стройку во втором стандартная коробка

Comment: чтоб "не бояться" и сравнивать можно использовать git (https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2), можно сказать, это обязательный инструмент разработчика.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать и сравнить оба в чем проблемы. Про100 официальный сделает кучу работы за вас под капотом, а в вашем туториале ручками. И официальный старается подготовить максимально общий проект для начала. Это ведь не говорит что его менять нельзя. Просто точка входа в одном случае котлован под стройку во втором стандартная коробка. Задача туториале научить работать, а стандартного проекта быстро начать. Выводы делайте сами.

Answer (score 0):

Create React App (CRA) дает уже готовые конфиги и избавляет от необходимости добавлять и контролировать версии библиотек по типу babel*, eslint* и webpack*. Так же это гарантирует что в разных проектах на одной версии CRA будут одинаковые конфиги

Только учитывайте, что вы не сможете настраивать конфиги webpack, babel и т.п. Есть возможность делать это через package.json, но не всегда

Необходимость менять руками конфигурации появляется не так часто поэтому это небольшая плата за отсутствие головной боли